# Changing layout indents

Tags: android, xml

I've the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".ArticleActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/article"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>
            <!--app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"-->
            <!--app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"-->
            <!--app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"-->
            <!--app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>-->

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The problem is that there is no indents. I read that it is because there is no bindings for textview. That's why I added lines which are commented. But when I add it to textview code, I don't see anything in this Activity. What's the matter?

Comment: Are you trying to make `TextView` center?

Comment: @Mohsen I'm trying to make indents for TextView. But they are the same, that's why probably yes

Comment: Maybe you want `paddingStart`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this xml I can see the TextView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ArticleActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/article"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:text="Hello World"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I believe you understand the constraints by their name.  
In your version you constrained the Bottom of the TextView both to the top and the bottom of the parent. Also the right side (end) both to the left and the right of the parent.